# String Reverse using user defined functions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reverse the string using stacks, but the thing is i'm defining functions on my own without using the library. Here is the code:

```
const int size = 50;
int top = -1;
char C[size];
int i = 0;

void push(int x){
    top++;
    if (top > size)
        cout << "Error: Stackoverflow" << endl;
    else
        C[top] = x;
}

bool isEmpty() {
    if (top < 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool isFull() {
    if (top > size)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void pop() {
    if (isEmpty())
        cout << "Error: The stack is empty!" << endl;
    else
        top--;
}

int Top() {
    return C[top];
}

void Reverse(char *C, int n) {
    // For Push
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        push(C[i]);

    // For pop
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        C[i] = Top();
        pop();
     }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Enter the string: ";
    cin >> C;
    Reverse(C, strlen(C));
    cout << "The reversed string is: " << C;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, according the code, the string should have been reversed but I get the following output:

```
Enter the string: Hi
The reversed string is: ii
```

I'm pretty sure that the push() is done properly, but I guess there is a problem in pop()?

Comment: You are trying to use `C`, the global variable, both as the stack and as the string to reverse. This won't end well. Avoid global variables altogether.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but I’m offering advice anyway. `if (top > size) return true; else return false;` is better written `return top > size;`. `push` should use `isFull` rather than duplicating the test.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In the future, please don't paste code samples [with an unnecessary amount of spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53135570/1).  Reduce the amount of space to make it easier for those reading your questions to browse it easily (trim it down as much as you can, so don't use braces and introduce extra lines if they're not needed).  Also, make sure your code sample is compilable and can be pasted into something like [an online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)... this creates a ["MCVE"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you want to reverse the string *in-place*, have a look at [this](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/820/1*RnUT5xT9BvNlUMnsRzi6Rw.png) idea.

Comment: For "char C[50]", the array indexes run from 0..49.   Please review your code of push().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same array both for the string and the stack, thus in `C[i] = Top();` you are replacing the first character in the last, losing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

const int size = 50;
int top = -1;
char C[size];
char stack[size];
int i = 0;

void push(int x)
{

    top++;
    if (top > size)
    {

        cout << "Error: Stackoverflow" << endl;
    }

    else
    {

        stack[top] = x;
    }
}

bool isEmpty()
{

    if (top < 0)
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {

        return false;
    }
}

bool isFull()
{

    if (top > size)
    {

        return true;
    }

    else
    {

        return false;
    }
}

void pop()
{

    if (isEmpty())
    {

        cout << "Error: The stack is empty!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {

        top--;
    }
}

int Top()
{

    return stack[top];
}

void Reverse(char *C, int n)
{

    // For Push
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        push(C[i]);
    }

    // For pop
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        C[i] = Top();
        pop();
    }
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter the string: ";
    cin >> C;
    Reverse(C, strlen(C));
    cout << "The reversed string is: " << C;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MukarramWaqqas If an answer solves your problem, use the "accept" check mark on the answer vs. leaving a comment (it's how the site works).